# Dependency Injection in Angular/ Calling a method that belongs to a service from a class

Tags: angular, typescript

I have a component that creates an object (of type TableDataSource) and in the constructor I am also passing in a method that returns a promise (save method), however when the method gets called by TableDataSource, the service the method belongs to is not defined.

How would I go about injecting the service into TableDataSource given that it has to be generic. In this case I need a method that belongs to ContactService, but in another component I would need UserService for instance.

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-contact-details',
})
export class ContactDetailsComponent {
  constructor(
    private contactService: ContactService,
  ) 
  {
    this.dataSource = new TableDataSource<IContactDetail>(this.save);
  }

  public save(item: IContactDetail): Promise<IContactDetail[]> {
    return this.contactService.save(item); <--- this.contactService is null
  }
}
```

This is the TableDataSource:

```
export class TableDataSource<T> extends DataSource<TessTableRow<T>> {

  protected save: (data: T) => Promise<T | T[]>;

  constructor(
    save: (data: T) => Promise<T | T[]>
  ) {
    super();

    this.save = save;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this case you need to bind the context to `save` method because when you assign the method in another variable and call this method through that variable you have lost the original context:

```
this.dataSource = new TableDataSource<IContactDetail>(this.save.bind(this));
```

---

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this